# Reducing all sound volumes except for my own app

Tags: vb.net, audio, volume

I'm wondering if it would be possible to simulate iPhone notification sounds on VB.NET, in the sense of how they are handled.

For example, if you get a SMS message on iPhone, while listening to music, the music volume is lowered to about 25% while the alert is played, then the volume is restored.

Could this be done with vb.net?

I've seen ways to reduce the system volume, but wouldn't this reduce the volume for my app as well?

I found this which works great, but I'd like to know if I can separate my app from this

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    Partial Public Class Form1
        Inherits Form
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE As Integer = &H80000
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP As Integer = &HA0000
        Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN As Integer = &H90000
        Private Const WM_APPCOMMAND As Integer = &H319

        <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
        Public Shared Function SendMessageW(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
               ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
               ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function

        Private Sub btnMute_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, _
                          Me.Handle, New IntPtr(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE))
        End Sub

        Private Sub btnDecVol_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, _
                         Me.Handle, New IntPtr(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN))
        End Sub

        Private Sub btnIncVol_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, _
                         Me.Handle, New IntPtr(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP))
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: So you have other applications that are putting out sound and you want yours over those, if I'm correct? Also it looks like your using unmanaged DLL functions...

Comment: Yes, Ideally I'd like sound from every other application, including OS sounds to fade down to 25%, play my alert sound at 100%, the restore all other applications back to 100%